# Can't change the innerHTML of div by Id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the innerHTML of multiple div elements. But everything I tried didn't work.

```js
var divIds = ["kartinka0", "kartinka1", "kartinka2", "kartinka3", "kartinka4", "kartinka5", "kartinka6", "kartinka7", "kartinka8", "kartinka9", "kartinka10", "kartinka11"];
var Inners = [
  "<img src='0.png' style='transform: translate(0px, -184px);'></img>",
  "<img src='1.png' style='transform: translate(90px, -160px);'></img>",
  "<img src='2.png' style='transform: translate(170px, -90px);'></img>",
  "<img src='3.png' style='transform: translate(195px, 0px);'></img>",
  "<img src='4.png' style='transform: translate(180px, 100px);'></img>",
  "<img src='5.png' style='transform: translate(100px, 170px);'></img>",
  "<img src='6.png' style='transform: translate(0px, 200px);'></img>",
  "<img src='7.png' style='transform: translate(-95px, 175px);'></img>",
  "<img src='8.png' style='transform: translate(-170px, 100px);'></img>",
  "<img src='9.png' style='transform: translate(-200px, 5px);'></img>",
  "<img src='10.png' style='transform: translate(-170px, -95px);'></img>",
  "<img src='11.png' style='transform: translate(-90px, -160px);'></img>"
];

document.getElementById(divIds[0]).innerHTML = Inners[0];

var counter = 0;
var previousDiv = "nothing",
  currentDiv = "nothing";

setInterval(function() {
  if (counter == 12) counter = 0;

  if (counter == 0) previousDiv = "kartinka11";
  else previousDiv = divIds[counter - 1];

  currentDiv = divIds[counter];

  document.getElementById(previousDiv).innerHTML = " ";
  document.getElementById(currentDiv).innerHTML = Inners[counter];

  counter++;
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="kartinka0" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="kartinka1" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="kartinka2" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="kartinka3" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="kartinka4" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="kartinka5" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="kartinka6" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="kartinka7" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="kartinka8" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="kartinka9" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="kartinka10" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="kartinka11" class="centrirane"></div>
<div id="nothing" class="centrirane"></div>
```

It simply doesn't work but it should... Doesn't matter if I call the Ids by name or from the array it doesn't change anything. Not the style.display or any property. Nothing works on these Ids and I'm already desperate.
Any help is deeply appreciated!

Edit:
document.getElementById(divIds[0]).innerHTML = Inners[0];
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

When I use alert and give it divIds[0] or Inners[0] it pop ups the string from these arrays. Its like these ids in the html part are not existing.

Comment: Check your error console.  You have  `currentDiv = divIds[i];`   but `i` was never defined.

Comment: Changed it, still not working.

Comment: It is, in fact, working just fine.  No results are visible here because the  images are 404, but if you change those URLs to real ones you'll see that they do appear.

Comment: (Incidentally, since you're only displaying one image at a time you could simplify this quite a bit by writing the image into the same div at each iteration, instead of using separate divs for each step. Or even just reuse the same image tag  and updating its `src` and `style` attributes.)

Comment: You don't get the point. It was like this the first time I tried it. It is not working and the images are 70x70 visible when i put the code there. It's not working with JS. Doesnt matter if i try to set the display property or w/e property i write, it's not changing it...

Comment: What's not changing what?  Repeating "It's not working" without saying what, specifically, is not working, is not likely to get you the results you want.

If you change the code snippet above to use real image URLs, you will see the images appearing at their actual sizes, and with the `transform` positioning working as specified.  If you're seeing 70x70px versions of the  images in your site, check to see if you have CSS in there that is forcing those images to be that size.   If there is some other problem, *please tell us what the problem is* if you want help fixing it.

Comment: They are real images. If I get the html part from the js and put it in there they will show perfectly. But when I try to execute the page with this js its just not showing anything. It's like they are no elements with these div ids.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16VEoucy92YppwfnXmTfNG0L6mpogJSY-

Comment: That drive folder isn't public. The error message (thank you for that) indicates that those DOM nodes don't exist at the time the script is running.  Is the script at the end of the page, or wrapped in a document onready handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function start()
{
    startDiv = divIds[0];
    document.getElementById(startDiv).innerHTML = Inners[0];
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById(startDiv).innerHTML = " ";
    }, 5000);
}
<body onload="start()"
```

Did the trick. Thank you Heiko Jakubzik and Daniel Beck for cooperatin.

Answer (score 1):

There is a loop "i" that is not defined. You should replace

```
currentDiv = divIds[i];
```

with

```
currentDiv = divIds[counter];
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Can you make sure the images can be loaded i.e. the path is correct?

Comment: If you want to load the images from google drive, you need to change the image source in your Inners array. Instead of "<img scr='0.png'..." you'd have to write "<img scr='https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aIiL_lFxvufbPWc_PjWIoE0gRW8htC2b/view'...".

Comment: No, I uploaded the code with the images I'm using. So you can see the result after I run it. I have these images inside the folder.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense :-). Try erasing the "style" attributes from your "<img>" tags and see if this helps. Maybe the "translate" px need adjustment?